# How to adjust transparency of Border?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to search for a CSS style to adjust the transparency of a border
it doesn't mean that I can't see the border but what I want is to adjust its 
transparency.

There is a case in stackoverflow about this but it is eliminating the border and what i want is just to reduce its transparency so its clearly a different case

Comment: apply color in rgba instead of hexadecimal value.

Comment: Why could you not use google for this question? Or just use the search function of this site.

Comment: I search but I see only transparent and border is not seen but I am seeking for the css to remain the border with less transparency sorry if I cant find answer from web but what I want is the answer below

Comment: the transparency you give is eliminating the border not adjusting its transparency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

best way to make border transparent is by using RGBA

```
div {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
    background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
}
```